# Is it possible to change the shortcut keys for back and forward a word on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

By default, in Windows 10 the shortcut Ctrl+Left and Ctrl+Right move the insertion point backward and forward a word.

I would like to change this to Alt+Left and Alt+Right.

Is this possible?

The reason for this is so that it matches the shortcuts on my Mac that I am using to remote into the windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered that you can't change the default shortcuts in Windows (goodness knows why).  Therefore, I used AutoHotKey with the following script which remapped the key combinations accordingly.  Works perfectly:

```
!Right::send, ^{Right down}{Right up}
!Left::send, ^{Left down}{Left up}
```

Comment: Remember it will apply globally not for Word only. See this [question](https://superuser.com/q/1357813) to apply it for a specific program.

Comment: Thanks. However, I was looking to do it globally, not just in MS Word - so all is good.